# Kind tell what should be in place of this Typo in Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory, definition, normed-spaces

I am studying Galois Theory from "Algebra" by Thomas Hungerford and I want to know the what should be this definition instead of this typo.

Image:[image]

In definition of norm you can see that on RHS of the equation in power it's not clear that what should be subscript of [F:K] .

Can you please tell?

I tried googling but while defining norm the webpages that appeared used a definition not involving [F:K] on RHS.

Actually I have the book downloaded from libgen as institutes are closed, an it have these problems 2-3 times.

I am unable to proceed.
Kindly tell what it means.

Comment: I would bet that it's $i$, for the degree of inseparability.

Comment: I agree, it's the inseparable degree.